# MongoDB update document object

Tags: mongodb, updates

```
user = users.findOne({
    "$or": [{
        'local.email': 'some@email.com'
    }, {
        'google.email': 'some@email.com'
    }, {
        'facebook.email': 'some@email.com'
    }] 
// do stuff with user object
```

So I have the `user` object. This is fine, after I'm finished with what I need from it property wise I wish to update some of the fields in this object now, I've tried the following without it working:

```
user.local.email = 'other@email.com';
users.update(user);
```

Is this not a viable way of updating a document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the better suited solution.

```
user.local.email = 'other@email.com';
users.update({
    "$or": [{
        'local.email': 'some@email.com'
    }, {
        'google.email': 'some@email.com'
    }, {
        'facebook.email': 'some@email.com'
    }]
}, user);
```

Comment: @chridam It actually *replaces* the found document with one you set as the second argument, in my case my `user` object. It however keeps the same `_id`.

Comment: Why was that better? You still haven't shown us what you wanted to do with `user` before updating it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I use some of the fields from the document acquired (`user`) to determine what will happen to it next, 1. it will be updated with new properties, 2. the document does not exist and a new one is created, 3. the document exists however the passwords are incorrect so nothing is done with the document. The document is also to be used further on after all of this, the reason why I need it in javascript object form.

Comment: It really would have been better if you had shown us that, rather than making us guess wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator to update your document as follows:

```
db.users.update(
   {
       "$or": [
           {'local.email': 'some@email.com'}, 
           {'google.email': 'some@email.com'}, 
           {'facebook.email': 'some@email.com'}
        ]
   },
   { 
       $set: {
          'local.email': 'other@email.com'
       }
   }
)
```

With the update method, you do not need to do another query which finds the document you want to update because the [**`update()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update) method takes in a query parameter which is the selection criteria for the update, the same query selectors as in the **`find()`** method are available. Read more on the update method in the Mongo docs **[here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update)**.

Comment: So I *must* do two queries to the database (first findOne then update)? :/

Comment: @KarlMorrison: please read the answer again. There's no `findOne` there.

Comment: @KarlMorrison The above does not represent two queries but rather an atomic update.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Perhaps you did not read my question well enough, I wish to acquire property values *then* update. Don't be so hasteful in answering!

Comment: @KarlMorrison: I did read your question - before the edit where you said you need to do something with `user` before updating it. You seem to think that `user` is a reference to the document in the database? It's not.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Hence my question, do I need to do `findOne` first *then* `update`? It's a simple yes or no answer; yes being you cannot use the javascript object `user` to update the document in the database(via `update` like I hoped, `insert` may use the object though), but must query the database *yet again* to update the values. Meaning *two* query calls to look for the same document.

Comment: @KarlMorrison: yes, I expect you will have to do a separate `update`, and also to understand that the document you have been manipulating after `findOne` may not exist by the time you get around to calling `update`. The document may have been removed, for instance.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Perfect thanks, a good explanation as to why this is so. I'm guessing this is a design choice.

Comment: @KarlMorrison: The copy of the document in your `user` variable has nothing to do with the document in the database, once it's been fetched. It is not a reference to the document in the database. Maybe if you showed us what kind of "stuff" you want to do with `user`, we could help you better.